# How to get values from a Requests response in Python

Tags: python, format, response

The response object is as follows.

```
[
 {"id":"value1","type":"value2"},
 {"id":"value1","type":"value2"}
]
```

How do I iterate in python and get the values of key marked as "id"?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to search for something like "python iterate list" or "python get value by key"?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simple iteration over the list.

```
resp = [{"id":"value1","type":"value2"},{"id":"value1","type":"value2"}]
for val in resp:
   print(val["id"])
```

I humbly suggest you to go through the basics and give it a try before asking your next question here. Thanks

Comment: I am new to python for sure but experts like you baffle me.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xyz.py", line 40, in <module>
   print(val["id"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str